# Output client-side console with casper/phantomjs

Tags: javascript, console, phantomjs, headless-browser, casperjs

Going through the casperjs documentation I couldn't find where I could see the console.log from client-side javascript. Is this possible?

Answer (score 44):

I'm not really sure to fully understand your question, but you can do something like the following:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(message) {
    this.echo(message);
});

casper.start('http://google.com/', function() {
    this.evaluate(function sendLog(log) {
        // you can access the log from page DOM
        console.log('from the browser, I can tell you there are ' + log.length + ' entries in the log');
    }, this.result.log);
});

casper.run();
```

Output:

```
$ casperjs log.js 
from the browser, I can tell you there are 4 entries
```

Comment: For me, I don't see 'from the browser'

Comment: It works for me when I use `this.echo`, I've edited your answer.

Comment: old answer, but to see something like `from the browser`, just add that int the `this.message` part of the function... like `this.echo("from the browser, " + message);`