# console.log doesn't work in CasperJS' evaluate with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Why when I use `console.log` in `evaluate`, it works:

```
casper.then(function() {
  this.evaluate( function() {
    console.log('hello'); 
  });
});
```

But this doesn't work:

```
casper.then(function() {
  this.evaluate( function() {
    setTimeout( function() {console.log('hello');}, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Related: [Output client-side console with casper/phantomjs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10783675/1816580)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Because you're mixing up casperjs and remote page environments. The `evaluate` function will execute code within the remote page env, so the `console.log` call won't output anything.

If you want to catch **remote** `console.log` calls, listen to the `remote.message` event:

```
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
})
```

Btw, [documentation for events](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html) is pretty much exhaustive, as well as [the one for evaluate](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate).

Comment: The ```setTimeout``` is the difference in between OP's examples. How does ```setTimeout``` change this? they are both being executed in the remote environment.

Comment: @nikkwong Since the OP didn't specify what they mean by *"it works"* and *"doesn't work"*, we can only guess. I would think that they haven't noticed that they are breaking out of the control flow of CasperJS and therefore forgot to also wait in the `casper` control flow. They probably exited too early. I doubt that we can get to the bottom of this despite the activity of the OP.

Comment: FYI - links are broken

Answer (score 19):

@NiKo's answer is critical.

I would also suggest adding the following, since if there's an error, you might not even make it far enough to print out a console.log() msg, and instead end up with silence.

```
casper.on( 'page.error', function (msg, trace) {
    this.echo( 'Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR' );
});
```

Answer (score 11):

CasperJS includes [ClientUtils](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html), which can be used from the remote page to easily log to the console of the casper script:

```
__utils__.echo('This message is logged from the remote page to the CasperJS console');
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on @odigity's answer, this makes casperjs die with a more familiar error/stacktrace:

```
var util = require('util');

casper.on('page.error', function exitWithError(msg, stack) {
    stack = stack.reduce(function (accum, frame) {
        return accum + util.format('\tat %s (%s:%d)\n',
            frame.function || '<anonymous>',
            frame.file,
            frame.line
        );
    }, '');
    this.die(['Client-side error', msg, stack].join('\n'), 1);
});
```

Comment: Fantastic! I was just looking for something like this today too. Shouldn't the utility module be `utils` though?

Comment: @Qcom, I think `utils` would be fine, since it's [_`sprintf` equivalent_](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/utils.html#format).  Where I was using it we already had [`util`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/util) available, so I just used that :)

Comment: Interesting, are you using casper in conjunction with node via SpookyJS or equivalent? To my knowledge casper doesn't integrate with the node module ecosystem by default.

Comment: We're just using casperjs on its own.  If you look at their [`patchedRequire`](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/a2c47c0452b5a1ede70971a098cc665b49c3b2ca/bin/bootstrap.js#L276-L285) you can see that it will try and load from node_modules.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the link! Very nice to know.