# failed to evaluate a remote function in casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Considering these simple html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 id='h1'>hello casperjs</h1>
    <a href='javascript: rmH1()'>remove</a>
    <script>
        function rmH1(){
            document.getElementById('h1').remove();
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

By clicking the `a` element the `h1` element is removed.
And next is my js code written in coffeescript:

```
casper = require('casper').create()

casper.start 'file:///Users/username/my.html', ->
    @capture 'before.png'
    @evaluate ->
        rmH1()
    @capture 'after.png'

casper.run()
```

However from the screenshots the `h1` element was not removed as well.
How do I correctly call the remote function `rmH1()`?

Comment: not duplicate, but might provide some insight: [CasperJS evaluate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864373/casperjs-evaluate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `element.remove()`. You should use

```
var h1 = document.getElementById('h1');
h1.parentNode.removeChild(h1);
```

Had you listened to the `"page.error"` event, you would have seen that `remove` is [not a function](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf).